# Option to auto refresh map every [n] seconds in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

Is it possible to make a CartoDB map auto-refresh using the latest data every [n] seconds using the web interface? I am using the SQL API to update with new positions and would like to see them reflected on the map automatically.

**Disclaimer:** I am aware of the CartoDB.js library, specifically the [refreshTime](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback) option for createLayer(). I have successfully created an HTML file following the tutorial to implement the auto-refresh layer. Just wondering if there is an easier way to do this via CartoDB website directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there's an option for this within the CartoDB website interface. Looks like you'll need to use createLayer(), etc. Perhaps someone from CartoDB will see this and then add it as a feature.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't set refreshTime from the UI, it should be done using javascript API as you point.

The code for this case would be:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, ...., {
   refreshTime: 2000 // 2 seconds
})
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer to expand upon it, please?  Anything less than about a paragraph like this gets flagged up for review.

Comment: @PolyGeo What would you add? the answer is as simple as that

Comment: Anything that would give more context like a link to the relevant part of the documentation, perhaps why you cannot see this being added as a feature to CartoDB, etc, etc  You seem well qualified (from your user card) to provide an answer - I'm just hoping that you will provide a longer answer because "about a paragraph" is considered minimum length for answers (and questions) here.